# Starting Python Some questions

Tags: python

Ive been programming for about a year so far all I have done has been Java and C.
I would call my self intermediate in those languages, but decided that i want to try to learn python.

I downloaded python 3.3 of the website and am slightly confused. I tested out some programs in the Python Shell, and it seems to be more of a calculator than a language. For example as soon as I click enter it compiles and runs whatever code i had in there. What should i be using for writing bigger programs with classes and functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is an [interpreted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language#Historical_background_of_interpreted.2Fcompiled) language, not a [compiled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language) one.

You are probably used to languages in which you write a program and then call a compiler to generate a "binary" file which is executable on your machine. In Python, you just tell Python to execute the code file directly, skipping the compilation step.

You should probably find [a decent tutorial that explains the basics](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/). There are many ways to find one: [here's a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988/how-to-learn-python).

Comment: Thanks. Also as a followup. What are the advantages of using a text editor such as VIM and then compiling in command line, over and IDE such as eclipse. 

I know Eclipse isnt a perfect program but to me it stil seems to beat the hell out of running in command line. 

That being said what is a good IDE for coding in python.

Comment: @RobertLemiesz these are all very standard questions, and they'll be better answered if you do some searching for beginner Python resources. Nevertheless, briefly: the requirements for a Python IDE are less stringent than for a Java IDE: all it really needs is syntax highlighting and the ability to run the program with a keyboard shortcut. I use Eclipse + PyDev but Pycharm, vim, emacs, and many others are also popular. Also, to be clear, _there is no __compiling___ -- Python just runs the script directly.

Answer (score 0):

Write your programs in `.py` files then execute them like so

```
python myfile.py
```

Via the cmdline, (on windows you might need to add C:\Python33 to your system path variable)